# After Microsoft update my headphones do not function. How do i reinstall headphones

Tags: windows-10

After MS updated my laptop the headphones do not work. Going to sound shows no headphone option. Do I need to reload drivers?

Comment: If it's a Bluetooth headset, you need to redo the [pairing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15290/windows-connect-bluetooth-device)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, reinstall previous driver or update driver are common methods. Uninstall current headphones from device manager and delete driver.

Restart computer, Windows will install driver automatically.

Also, disable automatically download driver for your products.

[image]